Truncation techniques in the proof of Area Law
I am currently understanding on the proof of Area Law in paper "Rigorous RG algorithms and area laws for low energy eigenstates in 1D" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.08828). In terms of the AGSP constrution, we are required to do the truncation on some subregions containing O(n) qubits. In Corollary 4.6, the paper claim that the norm of the truncated hamiltonian has norm $O(\ell + t)$, which would be a constant in the latter part of the paper by setting $\ell, t$ be a constant. But I am confused why the norm would not be $O(\ell + t + \epsilon_{J_L} + \epsilon_{J_M} + \epsilon_{J_R})$, in which case the norm would not be $O(1)$ by setting $\ell, t$ constant.

In RG you can coarse-grain system endlessly and thus make $\epsilon$:s to vanish.

Thanks for your reply! From my understanding, those epsilons are ground energy of the hamiltonians on the subregion J, M, L. But since each subregion may contain O(n) sites, the ground energy would not be O(1).

@Angelo_M Please add such details to the post; and why you think the scaling should contain the epsilons.
